# Why are my checkboxes not binding to my View Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox, model-binding

I have a view model for a business. This model conatains a view model for address, contact details and also an IEnumerable.

I use editor templates to display the checkboxes. The problem is when I'm on the edit action and post the form the categories come back as null. I have read a few similar questions but havent found a solution that seems to work.

I have looked into Custom model binders with no luck and currently I'm thinking I'm not displaying the right information in the Editor template. I know checkboxes need a hidden input to go with them and maybe my problem lays there?

BusinessViewModel

```
public class BusinessViewModel
    {

        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [UIHint("ContactDetailsEditorTemplate")]
        public ContactDetailsViewModel ContactDetailsViewModel { get; set; }

        [UIHint("CheckboxEditorTemplate")]
        public IEnumerable<CheckboxViewModel> Categories { get; set; }

    }
```

CheckboxViewModel

```
public class CheckboxViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

CheckboxEditorTemplate

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<ViewModels.BuyWithConfidence.CheckboxViewModel>>" %>
<table class="aligncenter">
  <tr class="tRow left"><%
    var intBreakLine = 0;
    if (Model != null)
    {
      foreach (var category in Model)
  {
    if (intBreakLine >= 2)
    {
      intBreakLine = 0;%>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tRow left"><%
    }%>
      <td>           
        <%= Html.Hidden(string.Format("Categories[{0}].CategoryID", i), category.CategoryId) %>
        <%= Html.CheckBox(string.Format("Categories[{0}].Checked", i), category.Checked) %>
      </td>
      <td><%=category.Description%></td><%
    intBreakLine = intBreakLine + 1;
    i = i + 1;  
  }
    }%>                        
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is a snippet of what the template is producing:

```
<input id="Categories_Categories_0__CategoryID" name="Categories.Categories[0].CategoryID" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input id="Categories_Categories_0__Checked" name="Categories.Categories[0].Checked" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Categories.Categories[0].Checked" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'd end up with 3 inputs all named as the CategoryId. Have you looked into using the `.index` trick for collection binding. Or, you could use the `array[]` notation.

```
<%= Html.Hidden("Categories.index", category.CategoryID) %>
<%= Html.Hidden(string.Format("Categories[{0}].CategoryID", category.CategoryID), category.CategoryID) %>
<%= Html.CheckBox(string.Format("Categories[{0}].Checked", category.CategoryID), category.Checked) %>
```

If the order will remain the same you can use `for(int i...`).

```
<%= Html.Hidden(string.Format("Categories[{0}].CategoryID", i), category.CategoryID) %>
<%= Html.CheckBox(string.Format("Categories[{0}].Checked", i), category.Checked) %>
```

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: I'm still getting null for the trader.categories when the post action is hit. I tried both the above and started i at 0

Comment: I've updated question with the html that it produces maybe you can spot something?

Comment: The resulting html should be named `Categories[69].*`. Why is it `Categories.Categories[69].*`? That would tell the binder to look for a property named Categories that has a collection named Categories.

Comment: I have used the code you stated above so I'm confused why it is doing it twice I've updated my code above to show thesnippet where it creates the checkboxes

Comment: It seems to prefix it because my BusinessViewModel has the enumerable called Categories which my check boxe view model sits within (see my question again) Thanks

Comment: weird. How to do render the template? `<% Html.RenderPartial("CheckboxEditorTemplate", Model.Categories); %>` I'm not sure what this `UIHint` attribute is...does it auto prefix all the input elements for you?

Comment: UIHint is new to MVC2 and is a way of informating .NET of which EditorTemplate to use (It's basically a partial though)

Comment: hmm...I haven't used templates yet. Maybe switch to the `Html.HiddenFor` and `Html.CheckBoxFor`.

Comment: Does CheckBoxFor use the same parameters I couldnt work out what it was meant to do different.

Comment: It creates the input name based on the linq expression. `Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Checked)`. It will name it correctly with the array notation. `Categories[i].Checked` I'm not sure if the double Categories prefix would still show up.